# Motion based human detection

Tags: algorithm, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

I am newbie in Image Processing and Computer Vision field. Recently I am trying to detect human in video using motion detection.

I am using this [dataset](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~labimage/Dataset/) and here it is its [Technical Report](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~labimage/Dataset/technicalReport.pdf).

Well I am trying to detect human using background subtraction method. I assume first frame as a background and subtract other frames from background and then I threshold that subtracted image to binarize it. It works fine only when background and foreground have totally different color intensity values.

But there comes places where foreground(moving human) and background (chair at that place) is of same color so the subtraction value becomes very less and human is not correctly detected and result separates it in to upper and lower half. as shown below
[image: Splitted Image]

Also as mentioned in [Technical Report](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~labimage/Dataset/technicalReport.pdf) page 5, video is highly compressed and other segmentation errors. which is making it hard to detect foreground human.

I am trying to look solutions online but available research papers are so concise that I am not able to make sense out of it.

Any help would be really appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

As npinti suggested me in comment to try convex hull so I tried to do it on the following blob image

[image]

It divided the image in to separate small connected blobs first and then connected them like shown in following images

*This is the legs part*

[image: leg part]

*This is the left hand*

[image: Left Hand]

And 3 other tiny images. But my problem is to connect these whole body parts to make it one complete blob.

**Reference**

1. E. Auvinet, C. Rougier, J.Meunier, A. St-Arnaud, J. Rousseau,
   "Multiple cameras fall dataset", Technical report 1350, DIRO -
   Université de Montréal, July 2010.

Comment: Not 100% sure hence the comment, but could you generate a convex hull using the black binary points and follow that hull?

Comment: You can try to use optical flow for movement detection.

Comment: To start with, you could also do subtraction on different color channel (r,g,b). It will cover a few more cases.

Comment: Yh I did that, thats is why it is much cleaner, also I tried to subtract in Luma space. but no luck.

Comment: So a newbie, huh? I'd suggest reading a book, say Bovik, The Essential Guide to Video Processing, Ch.3. for starters. Too wide to answer here, but thresholding is too strict and simple for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the blobs of the body parts, get the bounding boxes of them and merge the boxes that touch each other, or that are close enough.

To merge the boxes just create a box that completely contains the other boxes: with minX=min(minX of all other boxes), maxX=max(maxX of all other boxes)  ...